# Is it possible to add icon to each item of NSCombobox?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am working on form application. I came across a scenario where i need to provide a ComboBox to user. Now in order to make look and feel more appealing, i want to display a small image or icon before each item of that combo box.
Is it possible to add icon to each item of NSCombobox?

Welcome any comment

Comment: If you're coming from Windows, I wonder if the use you have in mind for icons in a menu wouldn't actually be *less* appealing on the Mac. Icons are very rare in menus here; unless the menu item directly represents an image, a menu item in a Mac app—including in a combo box—should not have one.

Comment: Probably worth a link to the relevant section of the Mac [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGMenus/XHIGMenus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000356-TPXREF116).

Comment: Apple uses icons in both Menu (Finder Go Menu) and ComboBox (AMPathPopUpButton). It is easy to add an image to a Menu, but I would also like to add to ComboBox.

Comment: I think the question should be answered and not diverted!